# Rabbitmq memory management and dynamic memory assignment in Proxmox VM

Tags: memory, proxmox, rabbitmq

I have a debian 8 VM (in proxmox) with dynamic memory assignment ranging from 512 MB to 4GB of RAM.

I have rabbitmq-server installed on that machine, and was wondering how the [memory workflow](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html) would work with this setup. I have set the memory watermark to 0.9, but of course, this is the 90% percent of the assigned memory (which is usually very low, approx. 900MB) at the time of starting rabbitmq-server. Using absolutes doesn't work either since it will get the minimum of the specified absolute or the assigned RAM. When rabbit starts, it reaches the threshold fairly quickly and blocks publishers and so on.

What would be the best approach to solve this issue (I'm a little lost here) - I want rabbit to use all available memory as needed -, should I request to have the memory always assigned or is there some way to setup rabbit to disable this watermark?

Thanks!